# How to protect private resources on a Web server

Tags: php, encryption, https, web

I have a resource which accessed by means of the Web.

For example, the page http://example.com/data.php provides some JSON data like this:

```
{"aa":"ss","aa":"ss"}
```

And I have an application that needs this data by means of reading the response from this webpage.

But the problem is that I do not want other people to access the page. I want this page only accessible by my application. No one else can have access to it.

So, how can I deal with this issue? Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Easiest way is to require an API key you give per account and verify by `referrer` in each request. Google does this more or less for many of it's systems like Google Analytics.

Comment: Referrer is trivial to change and some proxies strip it. Don't know I'd say it's reliable enough to use.

Comment: @alex - Alternatives? Changing and altering en masse are two different things.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not sure of the best alternative.

Comment: @alex - I was starting to wonder maybe I had something amiss here. The match of a client-side key and `referrer` should dispel many mongrels. Due to HTTP's request nature, without custom headers, I can't say I'd have much else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. (Assuming you mean you are using this JSON data client-side.)

If your application can read it, so can users.  There is nothing you can do about this.  Even if you had a way to totally secure the transport, it can still be read at the application end.

Comment: Given the web service the OP indicated was being used by their own app, this isn't actually impossible. You can use .htaccess to restrict access to the machine the calling app is on (if they're on the same machine, it would just be localhost).

Comment: Another way to do this, while still using .htaccess, is to put the webservices on a different port than the default :80.

Comment: @tamouse, Running the service on a different port doesn't prevent anyone from accessing it, just makes it a little less obvious.

Comment: @tamouse, My read of the problem is that he is serving this JSON to the client's browser, which is why I included this assumption in my post.  If this is not the case, then I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Wyzard no, of course not, just makes it a bit easier to isolate in .htaccess